# What is the derivative of tan(ax+b) with respect to tan(ax+b)?

Tags: calculus

I tried to solve this question. It is a multiple choice question.

First I took the derivative of tan(ax+b) which is $\sec^2(ax+b)$ but If I take the derivative with respect to x it will be a $\sec^2(ax+b)$.

what I find confusing is $d/d \tan(ax+b) = \sec^2 (ax+b) d/d \tan(ax+b) *(ax+b)$

I can't really understand this problem, I have been trying many times.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is
$$\frac{d}{dx}[\tan(ax+b)] = \sec^2(ax+b)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}[ax+b] = a\sec^2(ax+b),$$
where the second equality invokes the chain rule.

---

Edit:
Recall that $$\frac{dg}{df} = \frac{dg}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{df} = \frac{g'(x)}{f'(x)}$$
So, in our case $g(x) =\tan(ax+b)$. But $f(x) = \tan(ax+b)$ also. Therefore
$$\frac{g'(x)}{f'(x)} = \frac{a\sec^2(ax+b)}{a\sec^2(ax+b)}=1.$$

Comment: It would be the answer, If I take the derivative with respect to x, but in this case, I need to take the derivative with respect to tan(ax+b). So the answer may be different or the same as If I take it with respect to x?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but it sounds like it could be $1$. In other words, I think you are saying something like if $y = \tan(ax+b)$, then what you are asking is $\frac{d}{dy}y = 1$. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Yeah, it is 1. I got the point that d/dy y = 1 in this regard. But if we solve this problem with steps than how it could be solved. I am not sure about the steps.

Comment: I am a bit rusty on this, so I am not exactly sure. I would just make the substitution using the variable $y$, or I would just explicitly state that $\frac{d}{d\tan(ax+b)}\tan(ax+b) = 1$. I don't remember that much.

Comment: 1 is correct ans. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I did some reading, and I came up with another explanation.

Comment: What is that? Explain?

Comment: evaluate: $$\lim_{\tan(ax+b)\to 0}\frac{\Delta\tan(ax+b)}{\Delta\tan(ax+b)}$$